# python proton API on_accepted() - how do I get the details of the msg being accepted, from the event parameter?

Tags: python

There are a dozen "hello world" type examples I see where `on_accepted()` just counts the number of accepted msgs - where it is something to show that "a message" was accepted. However, I need to know **WHICH** message was accepted.

```py
def on_accepted(self, event):
    m_id = event.message.id
    self.logger.info( 'Accepted msg {0}'.format( m_id ))
```

This doesn't work because there is no valid message element in event, so I end up with a `NoneType doesn't have an id` type error.

I looked at the members of the event parameter and I don't see anything which I thought would make sense..

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find any references to how to read the message details, but I was able to find a work around which gave me the same info.

If I specify a tag on the send() call, like this:

`event.sender.send(msg, tag = msg_id )`

I can then read it in the receiver code like this:

`def on_accepted(self, event):
    msg_id  = event.delivery.tag`

Problem "solved"